# How to run an instance of a python script with arguments in parallel?

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to get the Script(flowcheck.py) to run as an instance, so that if the client sends more than one request in quick succession the scripts don't hang and wait for the previous request to finish.

Is there a way to make the server just run an instance of the script + arguments without monitoring it, then go back into listening for the next request?

Server Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import SocketServer
import flowcheck
import os 

class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):


    def handle(self):
        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print "{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0])
        print self.data

        flowcheck.flow(self.data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "", 5007

    # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 5007
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)

    # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
    # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
    server.serve_forever()
```

Client Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import sys

HOST, PORT = "192.168.8.201", 5007
data = " ".join(sys.argv[1:])

# Create a socket (SOCK_STREAM means a TCP socket)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    # Connect to server and send data
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
    sock.sendall(data + "\n")


finally:
    sock.close()

print "Sent:     {}".format(data)
```

Script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import time
#data = " ".join(sys.argv[1:])
def flow(data):
    var=0
    while var<3:

        print "FlowCheck",data,var
        var = var +1
        time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing the script, `import subprocess` using `Popen` to run an instance of the script in the background and continue taking requests.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import SocketServer
import os 
import subprocess

class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print "{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0])
        print self.data

        var1 =self.data
        subprocess.Popen([ "python", "flowcheck.py",var1])
```

Change to script to take system arguments with `import sys`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import time

print "start"
data = sys.argv[1]

def flow(data):
    var=0
    while var<3:

        print "FlowCheck",data,var
        var = var +1
        time.sleep(5)

flow(data)
```